# where is the Documents folder shown in iFile (iPad-Air)?

Tags: jailbreak, ipad, ios

There is a folder called **Documents** (and other folders beside that) in **iFile**

I tried but can't find the physical location with iFunbox or iTools.

How can I find the physical location of that folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download Apple file conduit "2" from cydia, Once you do you will be able to see everything that you want such as /var in Ifunbox in the raw system files section

Answer (score 0):

When using a system that doesn't know how to follow POSIX [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (like iFunbox), then you're going to need to know the actual location of the directory. When using iFile, it'll appear to be located at `/var/mobile/Documents/`, but in reality, `/var` is a symbolic link to `/private/var/`. So the answer to your question is: The `Documents` folder is located at `/private/var/mobile/Documents/`.

Comment: Thanks for Answer But I can't find '/' folder in iFunbox. there is a category called 'Raw File System' and can't see anything relative in that !

Comment: I'll have to look in to it further. I haven't used iFunbox in a while.

Comment: Tnx a lot , if you know better tool for PC mention that plzZ

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the files that have been downloaded to your device and are accessible via the “Files” application try going to /var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/1A268C0D-94CD-4503-9A09-6E08E12387AB/File Provider Storage/Downloads